# How can I do two operation using custom button

Tags: visualforce

this is my Apexclass :

```
public class OverrideButton {
    public Candidate__c can{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public OverrideButton(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    public PageReference SaveandView() {
        if(controller != null) {
            PageReference ViewCandidate = page.ViewCandidate;
            ViewCandidate.setRedirect(true);
            ViewCandidate.getParameters().put('id',controller.getId());
            return ViewCandidate;
        } return null;
    } 
}
```

this is my visualforce page for view:

```
<apex:page standardController="Candidate__c" extensions="OverrideButton,AttachCandidatecontroller">
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
     <apex:outputfield value="{!Candidate__c.Name}"/>
   <apex:outputfield value="{!Candidate__c.DOB__c}"/>
   <apex:outputfield value="{!Candidate__c.Interview_Date__c}"/>
    <apex:outputfield value="{!Candidate__c.Phone_No__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Candidate__c.Mail_ID__c}"/>  
    <apex:outputField value="{!Candidate__c.Qualification__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Candidate__c.Interview_Status__c}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
          <apex:inputfile value="{!myfile.body}" filename="{!myfile.Name}" />
          <apex:commandbutton value="Attachfile" action="{!Attachfile}"/>
    </apex:form>
     </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
this is my visualforce page for inserting:
<apex:page standardController="Candidate__c" extensions="OverrideButton">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock title="This page is created by:{!$User.FirstName}">
     <apex:pageBlockSection >
     <apex:inputField value="{! Candidate__c.Name}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! Candidate__c.DOB__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! Candidate__c.Interview_Date__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! Candidate__c.Phone_No__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! Candidate__c.Mail_ID__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! Candidate__c.Qualification__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! Candidate__c.Interview_Status__c}"/>
     <apex:commandButton action="{!Saveandview}" value="Insert Candidate"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>   
    </apex:page>
```

SOmeone give solutions to overcome this Issues. Thanks in advance

Comment: You posted some code, but it's still not clear what you are hoping to achieve. Can you add some detail?

Comment: Hi @nbrown I want to insert a candidate and on next page I need to view those records and then I need to upload files on that page itself and after uploading it renders back to candidate page

Comment: Are you stuck with inserting `Candidate__c` records when clicking the `Saveandview` commandButton?

Comment: Yes exactly AFter clicking save and view it just showing the label not values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a standard controller, you can leverage the [standard controller methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm) and use `save()`.

You can change your button method to the below, making sure you save the Candidate record before returning a page reference.

```
    public PageReference saveAndView() {
        if(controller != null) {
            controller.save();
            PageReference ViewCandidate = Page.ViewCandidate;
            ViewCandidate.setRedirect(true);
            ViewCandidate.getParameters().put('id', controller.getId());
            return ViewCandidate;
        } 

        return null;
    }
```